# How to get root element for scope in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I usually need the element's scope which is something like `$(element).scope()` or `angular.element(..).scope()`

But now I have the opposite problem - I have a scope, and I need to find which element generated it.

How can I find out from the developers' console which element it is?

## Why do I need this?

I am working on someone else's code, fixing a bug.

I am still trying to figure out some stuff, but some of the code is quite hard to follow. Very generic and a lot of copy-paste, so searches don't always help.

There's a lot of ng-includes and directives that use the parent scope.

There's a view calling a service somehow - it is unclear how yet..

I do have a reference to a scope, which is different from the one in the view that triggers the function.

So if I find the element from which that scope came from, it could sort out the relation between them etc..  At least give me some lead.

Obviously some refactoring and best practices are required in the future, but I have to focus on this bug first.

Comment: It can help if you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve. Because in most cases this is not an approach you would like to take. I'm trying to say that I cannot imagine the case when obtaining controller's element can be required. Probably there's a better solution for your task.

Comment: @RhinoLarva added explanation.

Comment: If you know which service is called you could try to search it's usages. It has to be injected in the controller / directive / another service. Most of editors / IDEs should be able to perform that kind of search on source files of the project.

Comment: @RhinoLarva - as mentioned in the question, there's a lot of repeated code and a lot of abstract code. search is not always helpful. Is there simply a way to know which element is connected to the $scope? In my opinion there might be one since scope is destroyed when element is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of nothing 'out-of-the-box', but every $scope variable has a unique $id property; and in addition, every element that has a $scope gets marked with the 'ng-scope' class. So something along the lines of the following VERY UGLY METHOD! may help (I'm assuming you have jQuery; otherwise substitute angular's jqueryLite methods):

```
function findById(id) {
    var els = $('.ng-scope'); 
    for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
        if ($(els[i]).scope().$id===id) {
            return els[i];
        }
    } 
    return null;
}
```

And if this is actually helpful, then I feel your debugging pain.

Comment: YES! HELPFUL! the `.ng-scope` thing is genius! Gonna try adding a function "$getElement" or something to scope prototype. Should make my life easier! Hope to refactor this code soon and have things organized!

Comment: Be sure to burn that function after use :). If you have to resort to this approach to debugging, there is something conceptually off about the code you're trying to fix.